# What questions to survey readers?

Tags: feedback, beta-readers

Is there any guideline or sample on how to survey readers? My blog is non-fiction, self-help yet academic style, which require some knowledge on philosophy and psychology. I'm unable to find any such guideline unfortunately.

Comment: See similar blogs/websites such as yours and see what they're doing.

Comment: What kind of survey is this? Beta readers? More info is necessary here

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the first step is to have clarity about the objective of the survey. The objectives can be to:

1. Understand the audience
2. Content improvements
3. Design improvements
4. Usability improvements
5. User experience improvements
6. Change or better alignment of the direction of the content

All the above objectives will have some common points but a better clarity about the preciseness of the other objectives will help in deciding about the framework in a better way.

You may also check some guidelines at https://survicate.com/customer-feedback/reader-interest-survey/